# How create two columns with same foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create two column with same foreign key . This is Error in Mysql.
**ERROR**

```
 errno: 150 “Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed”
```

**SCRIPT**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invictus`.`Votaciones` (
  `idVotaciones` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mvp` INT NOT NULL,
  `idPartido-Jugador` INT NOT NULL,
  `votante` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idVotaciones`),
  INDEX `fk_Votaciones_Partido-Jugadores_idx` (`mvp` ASC, `idPartido-Jugador` ASC, `votante` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Votaciones_Partido-Jugadores`
    FOREIGN KEY (`mvp` , `idPartido-Jugador` , `votante`)
    REFERENCES `invictus`.`Partido-Jugadores` (`Jugador_idJugador` , `Equipos_Partido_idPartido` , `Jugador_idJugador`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

**EDIT 1**

Here the table *Partido-Jugadores* , where I want to reference my two colums with *Jugador_idJugador*

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invictus`.`Partido-Jugadores` (
  `idPartido-Jugadores` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Equipos_idEquipos` INT NOT NULL,
  `Equipos_Partido_idPartido` INT NOT NULL,
  `Equipos_Partido_fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `Equipos_Partido_Grupo_idGrupo` INT NOT NULL,
  `Equipos_nombreEquipo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `Jugador_idJugador` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPartido-Jugadores`, `Equipos_idEquipos`, `Equipos_Partido_idPartido`, `Equipos_Partido_fecha`, `Equipos_Partido_Grupo_idGrupo`, `Equipos_nombreEquipo`, `Jugador_idJugador`),
  INDEX `fk_Partido-Jugadores_Equipos1_idx` (`Equipos_idEquipos` ASC, `Equipos_Partido_idPartido` ASC, `Equipos_Partido_fecha` ASC, `Equipos_Partido_Grupo_idGrupo` ASC, `Equipos_nombreEquipo` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_Partido-Jugadores_Jugador1_idx` (`Jugador_idJugador` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Partido-Jugadores_Equipos1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Equipos_idEquipos` , `Equipos_Partido_idPartido` , `Equipos_Partido_fecha` , `Equipos_Partido_Grupo_idGrupo` , `Equipos_nombreEquipo`)
    REFERENCES `invictus`.`Equipos` (`idEquipos` , `Partido_idPartido` , `Partido_fecha` , `Partido_Grupo_idGrupo` , `nombreEquipo`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Partido-Jugadores_Jugador1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`Jugador_idJugador`)
    REFERENCES `invictus`.`Miembros-Grupo` (`Jugador_idJugador`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

What is the problem? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want the correct syntax, you will need to show what the primary key for `Partido-Jugadores` looks like.

However, you have repeated a column twice in the foreign key reference:

```
REFERENCES `invictus`.`Partido-Jugadores` (**`Jugador_idJugador`**, `Equipos_Partido_idPartido` , **`Jugador_idJugador`**)
```

I've never tried this, but I assume that it is an error in the definition of the primary key, and an error in the foreign key reference.  Use the appropriate primary key definition.

EDIT:

If you have an auto-increment column in `Partido-Jugadores`, then that should be the primary key.  That alone with nothing else:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`idPartido-Jugadores`),
```

Then the foreign key reference would be:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_Votaciones_Partido-Jugadores`
  FOREIGN KEY (`idPartido-Jugador)
  REFERENCES `invictus`.`Partido-Jugadores` (`Jugador_idJugadores`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

Notes:

- You should name the primary key in the singular, in my opinion.
- You should not use `-` in table or column names.  Use `_` as a separator instead.  That way, identifiers do not need to be escaped.

Comment: I have added Partido-Jugadores in my questions. In my table *Votaciones* , the columns *mvp* and *votante* refer to *Jugador_idJugador* in *Partido-Jugadores*. *Jugador_idJugador* must to be primary-key?